# paste files without delimiter

Tags: text-processing, files, paste

How do I join two files vertically without any separator? I tried to use `paste -d"" a b`, but this just gives me `a`.

Sample file:

```
000    0   0   0
0001000200030004
  10  20  30  40
    2000    4000
            .123
            12.1
1234234534564567
```

Comment: Are you sure this what you get? `paste - d"" a b` will paste content from `stdin`, file named `d""`, `a`, `b`.

Comment: @cuonglm typo...fixed.

Comment: You were off by one character: `paste -d "" a b`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`paste` use `\0` for null delimiter as [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html#tag_20_89_04):

```
paste -d'\0' file1 file2
```

Using `-d"" a b` is the same as `-d a b`: the `paste` program sees three arguments `-d`, `a` and `b`, which makes `a` the delimiter and `b` the name of the sole file to paste.

If you're on a GNU system (non-embedded Linux, Cygwin, …), you can use:

```
paste -d "" file1 file2
```

The form `-d ""` is unspecified by POSIX and can produce errors in other platforms. At least BSD and heirloom `paste` will report *no delimiters* error.

Comment: Be careful when trying to derive something from the behavior from the so called "heirloom" tools. `paste` from this suite was written by Gunnar Ritter and is unrelated to the UNIX sources.The Bourne Shell from that suite was derived from the OpenSolaris Bourne Shell, but has it's own bugs as a result from a quick and hacky port to the deficits in Linux (e.g. an incompatible wait() implementation), check `(exec ps)` to verify a hang that is not present in the original and that is not present in my portable Bourne Shell.

Comment: BTW: paste on Solaris before ~April 2010 gives a "no delimiter" error with `paste -d '' file1 file2` but since then, paste is the paste implementation taken from David Korn and this permits -d "".

Comment: @schily: What do you mean "derive"? I mention heirloom `paste` because I had it and can test with it, I don't use it for "standard" or anything else.

Comment: @schily: And also I have tested with Solaris 11, its `paste` gave *no delimiters* error for `paste -d ""`, too.

Comment: Many people believe that tools with the brand "heirloom" are from original UNIX sources, but heirloom paste is not.

Comment: @schily: Yeap, I also used to think that, but changed my mind after read your answer in this site and played with schily tools chest b-). And you see I don't use the standard or something similar with heirloom tools chest anymore. Anyway, feel free to make the edit or raise your own answer to make it better.

Answer (score 6):

The solution is:

```
paste -d "\0" a b
```