# Replacing text in specific position from another file

Tags: text-processing

I need to replace the text from **File2.txt** to **File1.txt** between 5th and 8th position. It supposed to be any character between 5th and 8th position, I just need to replace with new characters in mentioned position and remaining position character should be same as it is.

**File1.txt:**

```
abcd9876efghijklmno
abcd9676efghijklmno
abcd9886efghijklmno
abcd9976efghijklmno
```

**File2.txt:**

```
1234
4321
6543
5678
```

**Expected output:**

```
abcd1234efghijklmno
abcd4321efghijklmno
abcd6543efghijklmno
abcd5678efghijklmno
```

Command I tried

```
sed '/substr($0,5,4)/r File2.txt' File1.txt >file_new.txt
```

Comment: Nice task to learn text processing in the shell. How did you try to solve it? What went wrong?

Comment: i couldn't even able to get the exact command to test it. thanks @Philippos

Comment: Few of us get a command exactly right on the first try. *What did you try?* Also, is each file just one line long?

Comment: And if you edit your question after it has already been edited to get the formatting correctly, why don't you have a look how it has been done and keep the correct formatting?

Comment: sed '/substr($0,5,4)/r File2.txt' File1.txt >file_new.txt is a command i tried  @Scott

Comment: Once posted the question, i came to know the formatting issue. so edited @Philippos

Comment: It may have more than 10+ lines @Scott

Comment: @PrakashBalusamy 10+ lines in both files or only in `File1.txt`? do you want to replace 5-8 character positions on every line or only some specific lines? and `substr($0,5,4)` looks like a function from `awk`.. do not mix it with `sed`

Comment: consider same number of lines in both files (File1.txt & File2.txt), and in every line i want to replace the every line. Please suggest some ideas. Thanks @Sundeep

Comment: I would suggest to modify your samples to reflect this... say 5 lines each and show the expected output...

Comment: Modified the samples @Sundeep hoping for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably easier to use combination of `paste+cut`

```
$ paste -d'\0' <(cut -c1-4 File1.txt) File2.txt <(cut -c9- File1.txt)
abcd1234efghijklmno
abcd4321efghijklmno
abcd6543efghijklmno
abcd5678efghijklmno
```

- `-d'\0'` so that the inputs are combined without any character between

  - See also [paste files without delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227941/paste-files-without-delimiter)
- `<()` is [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)
- `cut -c1-4` gives first four characters from each line
- `cut -c9-` gives all characters from each line starting from 9th position

Another way is idiomatic two file processing using `awk`

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0; next} {print substr($0,1,4) a[FNR] substr($0,9)}' File2.txt File1.txt
abcd1234efghijklmno
abcd4321efghijklmno
abcd6543efghijklmno
abcd5678efghijklmno
```

- `NR==FNR{a[FNR]=$0; next}` saves all lines from `File2.txt` in array `a` with line number as key
- `print substr($0,1,4) a[FNR] substr($0,9)` use `substr` to extract necessary characters and insert the lines from `File2.txt` in between

Comment: Thanks @Sundeep, it works good. between one more doubt 

File1.txt:

abcd9876efghijklmno1234
abcd9676efghijklmno2345
abcd9886efghijklmno3456
abcd9976efghijklmno4567

Expected Result:
abcd1234efghijklmno
abcd2345efghijklmno
abcd3456efghijklmno
abcd4567efghijklmno

How to replace the 20-23rd position character to 5-8th position ?

Comment: should be easy to modify... `awk '{print substr($0,1,4) substr($0,20,4) substr($0,9,11)}' File1.txt` bit of playing with substr would have helped you... if an answer solves your question, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers on what to do...

Comment: It's working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

This looks somewhat bizarre, but:

```
dd if=file1 bs=1 count=4 > file3
dd if=file2 bs=1 count=4 >> file3
dd if=file1 bs=1 skip=8 >> file3
```

You haven't mentioned copying over any newline in file2, and it looks as if you didn't want it (if there is one).

Comment: It's not working, I need to replace 10+ lines at a time in same position, always file1 & file 2 have same no of lines and i need to replace the values in file1 alone not in file2.

Comment: @PrakashBalusamy you are not helping yourself by not giving better input samples and expected output...

Comment: Edited the question @sundeep formatting doesn't looks good. Consider each word as skngle line in each file