# How do I move a line following match up to the end of previous line?

Tags: awk, sed

I have about 500 files of text files similar to the output below.

```
GigabitEthernet15/0/
1                                                               
GigabitEthernet16/0/
1                                                               
GigabitEthernet16/1/
1                                                               
GigabitEthernet15/1/
1
```

My goal is to have it look like this:

```
GigabitEthernet15/0/1                                                               
GigabitEthernet16/0/1                                                               
GigabitEthernet16/1/1                                                               
GigabitEthernet15/1/1
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605232/how-to-merge-every-two-lines-into-one-from-the-command-line

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227941/paste-files-without-delimiter for empty delimiter

Comment: This might not be a duplicate, since the OP might not want to join *every* pair of lines.  If there's a chance that the input will be more complex than in the OP's example, it may be helpful to trigger the joining when a particular pattern occurs.  EG, `awk '{ printf "%s", $0 } $0 !~ /^GigabitEthernet.*\/$/ { printf RS }' file.txt`

Comment: @Gaultheria It turned out this is exactly what I needed, I had some other examples that misbehaved.  If you want to put your comment as an answer, I will mark it correct.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. I'll be glad to do that if the question is reopened.  (I don't have enough reputation to cast a reopen vote myself, unfortunately.)

Comment: @JordanHead in that case you should add a sample input to the question that reflects your use case better... also, you are expected to show what efforts you made to solve this by yourself, hover the mouse over downvote button to see it for yourself

Answer (score 3):

With awk, get the next line and append it to the current line:

```
$ awk '{getline n; $0 = $0 n} 1' foo
GigabitEthernet15/0/1
GigabitEthernet16/0/1
GigabitEthernet16/1/1
GigabitEthernet15/1/1
```