# Merge every second line from two files

Tags: text-processing

File1:

```
A
B
C 
D
```

File2:

```
E
F
G
H
```

How would I get Output:

```
A
BF
C
DH
```

Comment: Welcome to UNIX & Linux at Stack Exchange. Please review the [tour] and the [How to ask a good question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the Help Center, the edit your original question and include details such as what environment you are working in, what you have already tried, any errors encountered, etc.

Comment: If any of the answers solves your issue, please consider ["accepting" the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). This is the best way to show gratitude on this site.  Accepting an answer not only marks the question as resolved, but also signals to _future readers_ that the accepted answer actually solved the issue.  More information about this is available here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
paste -d '\n' file1 file2 | sed -n 'p;n;n;N;s/\n//p' > output
```

`paste` zips the two files, alternating one line of each, and `sed` `p`rints the first, discards the second, appends the 4th to the 3rd and joins them and starts again with the next lines.

Or with GNU `sed`:

```
paste -d '\n' file1 file2 | sed '2~4d' | paste -sd '\n\0\n' - > output
```

Where `sed` just `d`iscards the 2nd out of every 4 lines from the output of the zipping `paste` and the second paste does the joining.

Or, still with GNU `sed`:

```
sed 'z;n' file2 | paste -d'\0' file1 - > output
```

Where `sed` zaps one line (in other `sed` implementations, you can use `s/.*//`) and gets and prints the `n`ext so we can paste it to file1.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '{ getline other <"file2" } { print $0 (FNR % 2 == 0 ? other : "") }' file1
A
BF
C
DH
```

For each line of `file1` read, this `awk` script also reads a line from `file2` and stores it in the variable `other`. It then proceeds to print the line from `file1` concatenated with the variable `other`, or nothing if the line number is odd.

---

A shell loop that would do the same thing:

```
n=0
while IFS= read -r a; do
    n=$(( n + 1 ))

    IFS= read -r b <&3

    [ "$(( n % 2 ))" -ne 0 ] && b=""
    printf '%s%s\n' "$a" "$b"
done <file1 3<file2
```

This loop loops over `file1`, each line being read into `$a`, and for each iteration also reads a line from `file2` (over file descriptor 3) into `$b`.  If the number of lines read from `file1` so far is odd, `$b` is set to an empty string.  Both `$a` and `$b` are then printed.

---

Using `paste` and GNU `sed`, and assuming that neither file contains tab characters (as they don't do in the question):

```
paste file1 file2 | sed '1~2s/\t.*//;s/\t//'
```

The `paste` will produce the contents of the two files side by side, separated by a tab character. The `sed` expression would first delete everything from the tab onwards on odd lines, and then delete all remaining tab characters.

With the same assumptions, the whole `sed` command above could be replaced by `awk`:

```
paste file1 file2 | awk -F '\t' '{ print $1 (FNR % 2 == 0 ? $2 : "") }'
```

Comment: The `3<file2` trick is neat. I didn't know you could do that. Unfortunately I can't see how use it for arbitrary inputs. (I'm trying to write a `zip` function which works the same as in python. I want all streams to *stop* when the shortest is exhausted)

Comment: @olejorgenb The loop, as it is written now, will stop when `file1` ends. To stop earlier if `file2` ends, test the return status of the second `read`, possibly by changing that line into `IFS= read -r b <&3 || break`.

Comment: @olejorgenb You could even change the loop into `while IFS= read -r a && IFS= read -r b <&3; do ...; done <file1 3<file2` (i.e. move the inner `read` so that it's part of the loop condition) but I haven't tested it.

Comment: (Sorry, I could have been clearer)
Yes, but I'd like a general function which can zip `N` streams: `zip <(seq 100000) <(cat file) <(cat file2)`

Comment: @olejorgenb This sounds like a new question to me. You should ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0;next} FNR%2==0 { a[FNR]=a[FNR]$0}  END{for ( i in a) print a[i]}' file1 file2
```

E.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "a
B
C
D" > file1
echo 'aa
Gd
Er
Yu
Ee
Tt' > file2
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$0;next} FNR%2==0 { a[FNR]=a[FNR]$0}  END{for ( i in a) print a[i]}' file1 file2
```

You will get output

```
a
BGd
C
DYu
Tt
```

Answer (score 1):

With perl  also it is possible to interleave the lines from two files in the desired manner. 
File 2 is on std in and file 1 is an argument to perl. 
The line from file2 is added alternately, then the newline is removed.

```
$ perl -pe '($_ .= ($,,$,.<STDIN>)[$|--]) =~ s/\n(?!\z)//' File1 < File2
```

Answer (score 0):

using `GNU sed`, we may do it as follows:

```
sed -e 'R file2' file1 | sed -Ee 'N;N;N;s/\n.*(\n.*)\n/\1/'
```

wherein we emulate the `paste` via `sed` and then string the 4 lines together and manipulate in such a manner so as to delete the 2nd and remove the newline between the 3rd and 4th. Repeat this process for the next 4-line slot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming input is on files z7 z8:

```
paste -d'\0' <(cat z7) <(sed '1~2s/^.*$//' z8)
```

produces:

```
A
BF
C
DH
```

This first deletes all characters on odd lines, leaving the newline. The paste then concatenates the files using a NULL character (thanks to thread [paste files without delimiter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227941/paste-files-without-delimiter) for the NULL tip).

This was on a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-7-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.11 (jessie) 
bash GNU bash 4.3.30
sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2
paste (GNU coreutils) 8.23
```

Best wishes ... cheers, drl